# Filling my state with API in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I want to fill my state with my API data (Characters),
but I can't even retrieve the data on the JSON (`console.log(json)`).
Someone have an idea to help me please?

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,


} from 'react-native';
export default HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const [Characters, setCharacters] = useState([

    ])
    const getCharacters = async () => {

        let response = await fetch(
            'https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/'
        );
        let json = await response.json();


        if (json.Characters) {
            setCharacters(json.Characters);

        }
        console.log(Characters)
    }
```

My console.log don't even appear:

[image]

Updated code with another API which doesn't works too:

```
const getCharacters = async () => {

    let response = await fetch(
        'https://reactnative.dev/movies.json'
    );
    let json = await response.json();


    if (json['Characters']) {
        setCharacters(json.movies);

    }
    console.log(Characters)
}
```

Comment: The api response doesn't have the `Characters` field. Copy-paste `https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/` into browser bar and see for yourself.

Comment: Characters is the name of my state. I want to put all the api datas inside Characters :      const [Characters, setCharacters] = useState([])

Comment: It works one time, but now it don' t working. I don't know why

Comment: `json.Characters` doesn't exit

Comment: I tried with antoher api : https://reactnative.dev/movies.json

when i wrote json.movies it don't works too, and movies exist

Comment: Can you please proved the updated code?

Comment: ok i did it on the answers

Comment: @LionelSYMR When we ask for extra information or clarification, you should [edit] your question, not post in the answer area.

Comment: @LionelSYMR "Characters is the name of my state. I want to put all the api datas inside Characters : const [Characters, setCharacters] = useState([])" Which part of the API data do you want to put inside the `Characters` state? You are trying to get a key from the API data that doesn't exist, so your state will be set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (json.Characters) {
    setCharacters(json.Characters);
}
```

The response from the API doesn't contain a `Characters` key, so this sets your `Characters` state to `undefined`. One solution that will give output is to just set `Characters` to the entire data from the response:

```
if (json.Characters) {
    setCharacters(json);
}
```

This will give you some data to display, but probably isn't the data you actually want. Most likely you need to make a request to a different end point to get the data you want.

Comment: ok  i tried and it don't works. I think the problem comes from my android studio
It works for some of my friends. Currently i did an update and i can t run again my virtual device. I will come back when it will be solve.
Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: @LionelSYMR I don't understand. What does Android Studio have to do with your question? I see you are using React Native. It sounds like you are running the app on a virtual device. The lack of data shouldn't have anything to do with the virtual device, though. If you can access any other websites on the virtual device, then the problem is with your code, not the virtual device.